# Why I have to pick types in child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, parent-child, children

I have these types and an interface:

```js
export type Plan = 'arcade' | 'advanced' | 'pro'
export type PlanDuration = 'monthly' | 'yearly'
export type AddOn = 'onlineService' | 'largerStorage' | 'customizableProfile'
export type AddOns = Record<AddOn, boolean>

export interface FormItems {
    name: string
    email: string
    phone: string
    selectedPlan: Plan
    planDuration: PlanDuration
    pickedAddOns: AddOns
}

export type DefaultProps = FormItems & {
    updateFormData: (fieldsToUpdate: Partial<FormItems>) => void
}
```

Also I have a component **PickAddOns** with components **AddOn** inside:

```js
export const PickAddOns: FC<DefaultProps> = ({
    pickedAddOns,
    planDuration,
    updateFormData
}) => {
    return (
        <>
            {(Object.keys(addOnsData) as TAddOn[]).map(addOn => (
                <AddOn
                    key={addOn}
                    addOn={addOn}
                    pickedAddOns={pickedAddOns}
                    planDuration={planDuration}
                    updateFormData={updateFormData}
                />
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

As you can see props type for this component (DefaultProps) has more properties than props I accept as arguments and it works just fine. But with component **AddOn** it works weird. **AddOn** here:

```js
type AddOnProps = DefaultProps & {
    addOn: TAddOn
}

export const AddOn: FC<AddOnProps> = ({
    addOn,
    planDuration,
    pickedAddOns,
    updateFormData
}) => {
    return <div></div>
}
```

I got an error in PickAddOns:

> Type '{ key: AddOn; addOn: AddOn; pickedAddOns: AddOns; planDuration: PlanDuration; updateFormData: (fieldsToUpdate: Partial) => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'FormItems': name, email, phone, selectedPlan

Could someone please tell me why this is happening? I just started working with TS and don't get why type **DefaultProps**, which has more properties than the actual props, works fine in **PickAddOns**, but gets an error in **AddOn**? Is there any solution without `Pick`?

Comment: Maybe you should've used `Partial`? https://tsplay.dev/m0YkPW

Comment: It could work, but every prop from DefaultProps is now possibly undefined. I don't know how to fix it right, but ! operator works fine. Anyway it looks worse than when I just Pick properties by myself.

Comment: Maybe you should pick properties manually then.